# How to query objects, each by its ID, from a nested data structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search, data-structures

I have a data structure which looks like this:

```
{
  FL: [{ ID: 1, confirmed: true }, { ID: 2, confirmed: false }], 
  TX: [{ ID: 3, confirmed: true }], 
  NY: [{ ID: 4, confirmed: false }, { ID: 5, confirmed: true }],
}
```

And I need to be able to loop over each item in this data and find the one that's `ID` value equals a known ID. I'm not sure about the way of approaching this.

The only thing that I can come up with is a for-in loop but I'd have to map over the arrays after looping over the object so that doesn't seem very clean.

Is there any method that is clean for handling iterations over such deeply nested data?

Comment: Ok none of this is helpful.. My issue is I cant figure out a way to loop over this just once to read the data inside the objects. I am still new to this...

Comment: [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) helps one to ... well ... find an object within an array, and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) returns all of an object's values as array, whereas [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) helps flattening e.g. an array of arrays

Comment: ... a straightforward search for an object with an `ID` value of `5` would look like this ... `Object.values({/* the object */}).flat().find(({ ID }) => ID === 5)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) helps one to find an object within an array, and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) returns all of an object's values as array, whereas [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) helps flattening an array of arrays.

The beneath implementation also uses an [*Arrow function expressions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as `find`'s callback function together with a [destructuring_assignment which is applied for unpacking a field from an object passed as a parameter to the callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter).

```js
function findObjectByID(obj, id) {
  return Object
    .values(obj)
    .flat()
    .find(({ ID }) => ID === id);
}

const sampleData = {
  FL: [{ ID: 1, confirmed: true }, { ID: 2, confirmed: false }], 
  TX: [{ ID: 3, confirmed: true }], 
  NY: [{ ID: 4, confirmed: false }, { ID: 5, confirmed: true }],
};

console.log(
  'findObjectByID(sampleData, 2) ...',
  findObjectByID(sampleData, 2)
);
console.log(
  'findObjectByID(sampleData, 3) ...',
  findObjectByID(sampleData, 3)
);
console.log(
  'findObjectByID(sampleData, 5) ...',
  findObjectByID(sampleData, 5)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

An even better approach, in case the OP has to query very often and repeatedly objects from the original data structure, was to transform this structure exactly once into a flat object which then serves as `ID` based map or index for custom data items (e.g. each item keeps the relation to its original category or meta key like `'FL'`, `'TX'` or `'NY'`).

The above provided example code then will be refactored into the next following one like that ...

```js
function createIdBasedItemIndex(rawData) {
  return Object
    .entries(rawData)
    .flatMap(([category, itemList]) =>
      itemList.map(item => ({ category, item }))
    )
    .reduce((index, data) =>
      Object.assign(index, { [data.item.ID]: data }), {}
    );
}

const sampleData = {
  FL: [{ ID: 1, confirmed: true }, { ID: 2, confirmed: false }], 
  TX: [{ ID: 3, confirmed: true }], 
  NY: [{ ID: 4, confirmed: false }, { ID: 5, confirmed: true }],
};
const categoryItemIndex = createIdBasedItemIndex(sampleData);

console.log({ sampleData, categoryItemIndex });

console.log('categoryItemIndex[2] ...', categoryItemIndex[2]);
console.log('categoryItemIndex[3] ...', categoryItemIndex[3]);
console.log('categoryItemIndex[5] ...', categoryItemIndex[5]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @CourtneyJ ... check out the second approach which transforms the original data structure just once into an easy to look up `ID` based map/index.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method that preserves the key as well as returning the match.

```js
let obj = {
  FL: [{ID: 1, confirmed: true},{ID: 2, confirmed: false}], 
  TX: [{ID: 3, confirmed: true}], 
  NY: [{ID: 4, confirmed: false}, {ID: 5, confirmed: true}]
}

const findFromId = (obj, id) => {
  for (let x in obj) {
     if (res = obj[x].find(a => a.ID == id)) return { [x]: res }
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(findFromId(obj, 5))
```